# CRAN failed submission - Warning: no function found corresponding to methods exports for 'show'

Tags: r, cran

I recently submitted my R [package](https://github.com/WojtAcht/hms) to CRAN, and I encountered a NOTE during the checking process. The NOTE looks like this:

```
Check: whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies, Result: NOTE
  Warning: no function found corresponding to methods exports from 'hmsr' for: 'show'

  A namespace must be able to be loaded with just the base namespace
  loaded: otherwise if the namespace gets loaded by a saved object, the
  session will be unable to start.

  Probably some imports need to be declared in the NAMESPACE file.
```

I'm seeking help to understand and address this issue.

`show` is defined like this:

```
#' Show method for class "hms".
#'
#' @param object - hms s4 object
#'
#' @return It returns the names of the slots and the classes associated with the
#' slots in the "hms" class. It prints call details.
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' f <- function(x) x
#' result <- hms(fitness = f, lower = -5, upper = 5)
#' show(result)
setMethod("show", "hms", function(object) {
  cat("An object of class \"hms\"\n")
  cat("\nCall:\n", deparse(object@call), "\n\n", sep = "")
  cat("Available slots:\n")
  print(methods::slotNames(object))
})
```

And in the NAMESPACE there is a line that looks like this:

```
exportMethods(show)
```

I was investigating if the show is defined correctly and the [GA](https://github.com/luca-scr/GA) package has a very similar `show` method:

```
setMethod("show", "ga",
function(object)
 { cat("An object of class \"ga\"\n")
   cat("\nCall:\n", deparse(object@call), "\n\n",sep="")
   cat("Available slots:\n")
   print(slotNames(object))
})
```

I could not reproduce this NOTE on my personal machine with Windows. On Mac OS I have never experienced this NOTE.

Comment: Perhaps it is because `show` is exported from the `methods` package. Do you need an unexported definition of `show` as `show <- methods::show`?

Comment: Which platform(s) generated the NOTE? And is there a url to see the results? I see you've got clean R-CMD-CHECKs across the board on your GitHub repo's automated tests.

Comment: Both [Windows](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/hmsr_1.0.0_20230903_171049/Windows/00check.log) and [Debian](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/hmsr_1.0.0_20230903_171049/Debian/00check.log) produced this note.

Comment: Dumb question, but: all my NAMESPACE export lines have each argument in quotes,  e.g.  `export("myfunc")`    .  Doesn't `exportMethods` work the same way?

Comment: In my case NAMESPACE has been automatically generated by roxygen2. It starts with: `Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand`

Comment: @AllanCameron could you elaborate on that? It makes sense that `show` is exported from `method`, but I don't understand what should I change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I got ride of this warning message by adding the following block of code in front of `setMethod("show"`

```
#' Show
#' @importFrom methods show
#' @inheritParams methods::show
#' @export
show <- methods::show
```

Add adding `methods` to the `Imports:` section in the `DESCRIPTION` file